# ¿Por qué me arroja un error por consola al tratar de accesar a removeChild en Javascript, es decir, cuando elimino un elemento del DOM?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, dom, eliminar, listener

Salta un error por consola cuando elimino los elementos añadidos por el DOM, en este caso tareas, pero no encuentro la causa, aun cuando sé que javascript me dice que al leer o trata de accesar al elemento removeChild su valor no lo encuentra o está vacío... El error que arroja es "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') at HTMLLIElement."  Dicho elemento se elimina, si, pero con ese error por consola y se refiere a la tercera línea del primer ciclo for

```
// variables
let lista = document.getElementById("lista")
let tareaInput = document.getElementById("tareaInput")
let btnNuevaTarea = document.getElementById("btn-agregar")

// Funciones
let agregarTarea = function () {
    let tarea = tareaInput.value
    let enlace = document.createElement("a")
    let contenido = document.createTextNode(tarea)
    let nuevaTarea = document.createElement("li")

    if (tarea === "") {
        tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Agrega una tarea valida")
        tareaInput.className = "error"
        return false;
    }

    enlace.appendChild(contenido);
    enlace.setAttribute("href", "#");
    nuevaTarea.appendChild(enlace);
    lista.appendChild(nuevaTarea);

    tareaInput.value = ""

    for (let i = 0; i <= lista.children.length - 1; i++) {
        lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        });
    }

};
let comprobarInput = function () {
    tareaInput.className = "";
    tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Agrega tu tarea");
};

let eleminarTarea = function () {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};

// Eventos

// Agregar Tarea
btnNuevaTarea.addEventListener("click", agregarTarea);

// Comprobar Input
tareaInput.addEventListener("click", comprobarInput);

// Borrando Elementos de la lista
for (let i = 0; i <= lista.children.length - 1; i++) {
    lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", eleminarTarea);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba a cambiar tu bucle for de

```
for (let i = 0; i <= lista.children.length - 1; i++) {
        lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        });
}
```

a

```
for (let i = 0; i <= lista.children.length - 1; i++) {
        lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.parentNode !== null) {
                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            }
        });
}
```

Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo :)